# Getting the error "Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter" when defining a type for a yumrepo

Tags: puppet

I am trying to define a type to create yum repos. I want to be able to pull the data from common.yaml and have this define pull in that data and act upon it. I have not gotton that far and I am getting an error for a invalid paramter. My code is this..

```
define xh_yumrepo::create_xh_yumrepo (
          $descr      =  '',
          $baseurl   =  $baseurl,
          $enabled   =  $enabled,
          $gpgcheck  =  $gpgcheck,

 ){

          $ensure    = 'present'
 notify{"title is $title":}
     yumrepo { $title:
         baseurl   =>  $baseurl,
         ensure    =>  present,
         descr     =>  $descr,
         enabled   =>  $enabled,
         gpgcheck  =>  $gpgcheck,
     }
 }

class xh_system::xh_yumrepo (

$yumrepo=hiera_hash('xh_yumrepo', undef),


){

    $os=$yumrepo[$operatingsystem]
    $rel=$os[$operatingsystemmajrelease]
    notify {"$rel":}
    create_resources("@xh_yumrepo::create_xh_yumrepo",$rel)
    Xh_yumrepo::Create_xh_yumrepo <| |>
}
```

the data is like this

```
  CentOS:
    "6":
      epel-6:
        descr: EPEL mirror for RHEL/CentOS 6.x 86_64
        baseurl:   http://repo.example.com:8080/epel/x86_64/6
        enabled:   1
        gpgcheck:  0
```

Every time it gets run the parameter ensure is

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Invalid parameter ensure at
>   /app/copa/puppet/conf/environments/qa/modules/xh_system/manifests/xh_yumrepo.pp:17
>   on node qa-test.example.com

hardcoding the ensure parameter or defining it in the common.yaml give the same error. According to [Type yumrepo](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#yumrepo-attributes) it is a valid parameter. I am stuck on what is causing the error since the parameter is valid, commenting out the ensure lines the puppet script works.

Comment: I fail to reproduce with Puppet `3.7.1`. What is your version?

Comment: we are using puppet 3.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `ensure` for `yumrepo` is not really supported before Puppet 3.5.1. There are multiple issues even in 3.5.0. See this [ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2163).